# Pl/SQL function returns string with changed characters

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

How to write a simple function that returns in parameter changed so it doesn't contain certain symbols anymore?

`(č=>c, ć=>c, š=>s, đ=>d, ž=>z..) 
 e.g. *đurđević* => '*djurdjevic*'
 e.g. *kuća* => *kuca*
 e.g.  *čaćkati* => *cackati*`

I have no code so far. I am very new at this and am trying to learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Croatian characters you can use a combination of `TRANSLATE` and `REPLACE`, since `TRANSLATE` doesn't support one to many translation (e.g. đ => dj).

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE('đak žvakaća čičak šuma','žćčš', 'zccs'), 'đ', 'dj') out FROM dual;
```

And the output:

```
out
--------------------------
djak zvakaca cicak suma
```

**Edit**

So here are two wrapper functions which implements this feature. The first one uses the built-ins while the other one has its own custom implementation.

```
-- first
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_translate(p_string IN VARCHAR) 
RETURN VARCHAR 
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN REPLACE(TRANSLATE(p_string,'žćčš', 'zccs'), 'đ', 'dj');
END;

-- second
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_translate_custom(p_string IN VARCHAR) 
RETURN VARCHAR 
AS
    v_current varchar(1);
    v_retval VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(p_string) LOOP
        v_current := SUBSTR(p_string, i, 1);

        v_retval := v_retval || CASE v_current
                                    WHEN 'č'  THEN 'c'
                                    WHEN 'ć'  THEN 'c'
                                    WHEN 'ž'  THEN 'z'
                                    WHEN 'š'  THEN 's'
                                    WHEN 'đ'  THEN 'dj'
                                    ELSE v_current
                                END;                                
    END LOOP;

   RETURN v_retval;
END;
```

And some test code.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Built-in: ' || f_translate('đak žvakaća čičak šuma'));

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Custom: ' || f_translate_custom('đak žvakaća čičak šuma'));

END;
```

Comment: thank you. but how to form this into a function with proper structure

Answer (score 0):

Check out translate
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php

Example:

```
TRANSLATE('1tech23', '123', '456')
Result: '4tech56'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [convert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html#GUID-C8BA0657-61C8-4964-A4CB-9292390853F6) function.

```
SELECT CONVERT('Ä Ê Í Õ Ø A B C D E ', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8ISO8859P1') 
   FROM DUAL; 

CONVERT('ÄÊÍÕØABCDE' 
--------------------- 
A E I ? ? A B C D E ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you can get without creating any structure:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('čaćkati', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))
FROM dual;
```

If you have a lot of combinations, I suggest on creating a table with possible combinations and using the `TRANSLATE` function.